# I am reloading my tableView after fetching data from API and after reloading tableView simply does not render any cell as I see in view debugger

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, reloaddata, swift5

This is my API Fetch method where I am reloading my tableview.After reloading tableview does not render any cell.

````
           ```
          API.shared.fetchAccomodations(completion: { (accResponse, error) in

        if let err = error {

            print("Failed to fetch accomodation Information ::" , err.localizedDescription)
        }
        if let response = accResponse {

            self.accomodationsData = response

            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                self.accomodationsData = response

                print(self.accomodationsData.count , self.accomodationsData)

                self.tableView.reloadData()

                 }

        }


      }, tokenURL: accomodationsURL)
       ```
````

Comment: Did you check the data array after API fetch? is it changed?

Comment: you can also check in numberOfRow method if the datasource count is 0?

Comment: I have done this multiple times before this is not my first time fetching data and reloading tablview.

Comment: Problem is that datasource is changed array has the data but tableview simply just not rendering cells even in view debugger window under the tableview heirarchy there is only  a uiview and not the custom cells

Comment: The only new thing I have done this time is that I have two tableviews in my VC

Comment: and also that I'm setting tableview height to content size

Comment: @DilanAnuruddha  Waiting for your response

Comment: @AhsanMughal did you set the tableview delegate? if you have two tableviews you have to use switch in delegate methods. can you add the delegate methods related to tableview

Comment: Already done that let me show you

Comment: if tableView == courseInfoTableView {
              return numberOfCourses
            

        }
        else {
            return accomodationsData.count 
        }

Comment: same thing has been applied in cellforrowat method also

Comment: Thats the reason I'm depressed :D I'm not a newbie I know these things but still can;t figure it out whats happening

Comment: Would really appreciate If someone want to have a look at the code and identify where I'm going wrong

Comment: how can we look your code?

Comment: I can send you via email

Comment: The problem is occuring in one VC so you can directly check that swift file

Comment: @DilanAnuruddha is that possible?
On solving you can put an answer and I'll accept that

Comment: @DilanAnuruddha Waiting for your response

Comment: can you you put it to git?

Comment: I have it in email so I can just send you in minutes.putting it on git will take time.

Comment: Waiting for your response

Comment: did you send the files?

Comment: your email message gets deleted kindly send again

Comment: Kindly send email again may be in a secure way so it not get deleted